# Are there any code samples for spring integration dsl error handling?

Tags: spring-integration

The JmsTests.java was very helpful in understanding ways to structure my code. Code is at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/jms/JmsTests.java

But, for error handling, I am kind of figuring it out as we go. Are there any tests or reference code that show good ways to structure error channels or using sub-flows to delegate error handling?

**Adding more context to the question:**

1. jmsMessageDrivenFlow: reads from incoming queue and prints payload. If there is an error, then it is sent to errorChannel()
2. handleErrors(): Is supposed to listen to errorChannel and send anything there to the fatalErrorQueue

jmsMessageDrivenFlow() works fine and prints the message. I am expecting the error handler to be called only if there is an error during the jmsMessageDrivenFlow. However, the errorhandler() also gets called, and it puts a 'Dispatcher failed to deliver Message' message in the fatal queue.

I am hoping that the error channel shouldn't even be invoked in this scenario since jmsMessageDrivenFlow() didn't create any errors. Obviously, if I leave out .errorChannel(errorChannel()) in the jmsMessageDrivenFlow(), the error flow is not invoked and I get only jmsMessageDrivenFlow() executing as expected.

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Component
@Configuration
public class MessageReceiver {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageReceiver.class);
    String fatalErrorQueue = "fatal";
    String incomingQueue = "incoming";

    @Autowired
    private JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate;

    @Bean
    public Queue incomingQueue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue(incomingQueue);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel errorChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow handleErrors() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("errorChannel")
                .handle((payload,headers) -> {
                    System.out.println("processing error: "+payload.toString());
                    return payload;
                })
                .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(jmsMessagingTemplate.getConnectionFactory()).destination(fatalErrorQueue))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(
                        Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(jmsMessagingTemplate.getConnectionFactory())
                                .destination(incomingQueue)
                                .errorChannel(errorChannel())
                )
                .handle((payload,headers) ->{
                    System.out.println("processing payload: "+payload.toString());
                    return payload;
                })
                .get();
    }
}
```

Log of the execution:

```
2016-01-22 10:18:20,531 DEBUG DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1 ServiceActivatingHandler.handleMessage - ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.dsl.LambdaMessageProcessor@522d5d91] (org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler#1) received message: GenericMessage [payload=SAMPLE QUEUE MESSAGE, headers={jms_redelivered=false, jms_correlationId=, jms_type=, id=78d5456e-4442-0c2b-c545-870d2c177802, priority=0, jms_timestamp=1453479493323, jms_messageId=ID:crsvcdevlnx01.chec.local-47440-1453310266960-6:2:1:1:1, timestamp=1453479500531}]
processing payload: SAMPLE QUEUE MESSAGE
2016-01-22 10:18:20,535 DEBUG DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1 DirectChannel.send - preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, headers={id=dc87f71d-a38c-4718-a2e9-2fba2a7c847c, timestamp=1453479500535}]
2016-01-22 10:18:20,535 DEBUG DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1 ServiceActivatingHandler.handleMessage - ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.dsl.LambdaMessageProcessor@5545b00b] (org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler#0) received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, headers={id=dc87f71d-a38c-4718-a2e9-2fba2a7c847c, timestamp=1453479500535}]
processing error: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
2016-01-22 10:18:20,535 DEBUG DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1 DirectChannel.send - preSend on channel 'handleErrors.channel#0', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, headers={id=f434348c-f659-1e88-2eba-3d467761ab47, timestamp=1453479500535}]
2016-01-22 10:18:20,535 DEBUG DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1 JmsSendingMessageHandler.handleMessage - org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler#0 received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, headers={id=f434348c-f659-1e88-2eba-3d467761ab47, timestamp=1453479500535}]
2016-01-22 10:18:20,537 DEBUG DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1 DynamicJmsTemplate.execute - Executing callback on JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:MACD13-60edd8d-49463-1453479492653-1:1:1,started=true} java.lang.Object@858db12
2016-01-22 10:18:20,568 DEBUG DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1 DynamicJmsTemplate.doSend - Sending created message: ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, messageId = null, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = null, destination = null, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 0, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = false, type = null, priority = 0, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@559da78d, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {timestamp=1453479500535}, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false}
2016-01-22 10:18:20,570 DEBUG DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1 DirectChannel.send - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'handleErrors.channel#0', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, headers={id=f434348c-f659-1e88-2eba-3d467761ab47, timestamp=1453479500535}]
2016-01-22 10:18:20,571 DEBUG DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1 DirectChannel.send - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, headers={id=dc87f71d-a38c-4718-a2e9-2fba2a7c847c, timestamp=1453479500535}]
```

Comment: As you see guys here don't like your question. You should re-phrase it a bit with some code on the matter. And point there where you would like to see error-handling.

Comment: thx for reply. added sample code to explain the need for an example

Comment: Sorry, who is `errorhandler()`? I don't see any point for that in your config

Comment: my bad. handleErrors() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Thanks. Investigating... But from the big height everything works as expected:

1. Your `jmsMessageDrivenFlow()` is one-way flow
2. You have non-end `.handle()` in the end of that flow:

   ```
   .handle((payload,headers) ->{
                   System.out.println("processing payload: "+payload.toString());
                   return payload;
               })
   ```

   Since you return anything, the flow expect the `output-channel` or `replyChannel` in headers. The `ErrorMessage` says you about that.
3. I tell that about the approach to fix the error altogether. For your case you can just change `.handle((payload,headers) ->` to the `.handle(message ->`
   which is one-way to stop your flow exactly there.

Since you really have that issue for the next endpoint after that replying `.handle()`, the `messagingGateway` reacts for that correctly:

```
        this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(requestChannel, object, this.historyWritingPostProcessor);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        MessageChannel errorChannel = getErrorChannel();
        if (errorChannel != null) {
            this.messagingTemplate.send(errorChannel, new ErrorMessage(e));
        }
```

And that's why your `handleErrors()` is able to handle that error.

Without `errorChannel()` on the `Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter()` we end up in the `AbstractMessageListenerContainer`:

```
protected void executeListener(Session session, Message message) {
    try {
        doExecuteListener(session, message);
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        handleListenerException(ex);
    }
}
```

where its default `ErrorHandler` is ... `null` and we see only:

```
logger.warn("Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.", ex);
```

Isn't it?

**UPDATE**

> Can you please explain why messagingGateway sends the payload to errorChannel() just because I have defined an error channel for non-happy-path scnenarios.

??? You will end up with the same error even with the XML definition. The Java DSL uses the same components on the background. I won't explain the regular Java code: you see the `try...catch` around `convertAndSend` and your condition at runtime defines that there is something wrong. That's why you get that `DestinationResolutionException`. we can't identify non-happy-path during init phase, because your `return` in the `.handle()` can be lucky `null` only at runtime. So, from the configuration perspective everything is OK. From other side even without `outputChannel` you still can be happy there with the `request/reply` scenarion, when we have `replyChannel` header on the matter.

Comment: I can terminate the handle(message ->) that makes jmsMessageDrivenFlow() successful. Just tested and that works. However, if tomorrow, I want to continue processing the message and not terminate with System.out, then I will end up with same problem.   If I add the .errorChannel() to the messageDriverChannelAdapter, why would the framework turn into the messagingGateway's logic. I guess I don't understand the impact of adding errorChannel to the messaging adapter.

Comment: Well, you can continue the flow as much as possible you should just understand that it is `one-way` and you should terminate it somewhere. Sometimes it's even enough return `null` from the `.handle()`

Comment: Thanks much. I think the happy-path flow is one-way flow makes perfect sense. And, that is exactly what I was going for. It just baffled me that just because I added error channels for error conditions, the handleErrors() flow would be invoked even when there are no errors in the jmsMessageDrivenFlow(). IIRC in the spring integration XML flow, the error-channel is invoked only for error conditions.   Can you please explain why messagingGateway sends the payload to errorChannel() just because I have defined an error channel for non-happy-path scnenarios.

Comment: See an UPDATE to my answer.

Comment: I guess that comment about XML intg working wasn't fair on my part. The code would give issues regardless.  Still, an open question about why messagingGateway sends the payload to errorChannel() even when there is no errors in the happy-path. Let me dig thru the code more and try to figure out. If I can't, I will open another question about this one. Very much appreciate your time and explanation. thanks.